# Migrating Off Zend Server

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-server

We have a customer with an existing PHP app running on Zend server. Don't have a lot more info yet, about what version of the server it is, but there is not a lot of documentation and no way to talk to the original devs.

It looks like it runs on the old community edition of Zend, and there is no such thing anymore. We are going to move them to AWS for hosting. We have zero experience with Zend. How difficult would it be to migrate off Zend? As I understand it, they have their own framework, so I'm assuming we would have to rewrite a bunch of code to another framework, or not use a framework, and rewrite to that. Originally we were thinking this would be a simple migration, but I'm not so sure that will be the case now. If anyone has any thoughts on migrating the CE of Zend along with the code, that would be great, as well.

I'm going to be reviewing the code shortly. Are there any things I should look for that would indicate how deeply they are using the framework now, that I'll have to think about converting?

Comment: Send server and Zend Framework are not the same thing. This question seems to confuse the two of them? You don't need Zend Server to run Zend Framework, it will run quite happily under Apache or nginx without modification. If it is old code, your biggest issue will probably be with the version of PHP.

Comment: Ah, I'm seeing that now. I thought you needed the server to run the framework. Will just have to try it. Thanks.